# SciPy's ctypes Fibonacci example fails to run with "array must have data type int64" error

Tags: python, c, numpy, scipy, ctypes

I am trying to reproduce [this](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Ctypes#head-6a582bd7b101bca0df6e5631a06e2d1d76e35a95) SciPy CookBook example.

I am following the simple instructions given on the website and I get the error below.

Any idea what is going wrong ? How can I make `fibseries` work ?

```
>>> fb.fib(8)
13
>>> fb.fibseries([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "fibonacci.py", line 38, in fibseries
    _libfibonacci.fibseries(b, len(b), result)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: array must have data type int64
```

I am running Python 2.7.6.

Answer (score 0):

The code has to be modified at line 21-22 like this :

```
_libfibonacci.fibseries.argtypes = [nm.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype = nm.intc),\
                                     ct.c_int,\
                                     nm.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype = nm.intc)]
```

from the original :

```
_libfibonacci.fibseries.argtypes = [nm.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype = nm.int),\
                                     ct.c_int,\
                                     nm.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype = nm.int)]
_libfibonacci.fibseries.restype  = ct.c_void_p
```

This solves the problem.

Edit: I don't know why this solves the problem, I was just trying out random things and this worked. I would be happy to know why this works.

I hope at least, however, that this solution will help others facing the same problem.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what the problem actually is and *why* the change is necessary